Run ajax call after close modal form ASP.NET Core
I am using ASP.NET Core 6. I have a razor view that has a section in it that is populated by an Ajax call:
 <div id="assessmentTablesDiv">
     <!-- ...content... -->
 </div>

This <div> is populated with the following call:
var assessmentTablesDiv = $('#assessmentTablesDiv');
var id = $('#adminDetailsAndOverviewId').val();

$.ajax({
      url: "@Url.Action("LoadAssessmentTables", "Assessments")",
      data: { id:id },
      type: "GET",
          success: function (data) {
          assessmentTablesDiv.replaceWith(data);
      }
});

The <div> is replaced with a partial view that has a button that calls a modal form.
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-2 mt-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn-sm btn-primary float-right"
                data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-target="#mdAddAssessment"
                data-url="@Url.Action("Create", "Assessments")"
                title="Click add an assessment.">
        Add Assessment
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

When I press the save button on the modal form, data is saved and the modal is closed. I then want to run the Ajax call to replace the data in assessmentTablesDiv to show the newly saved data.
I have tried the following code, but it doesn't work:
$("#btnSave").on('click', function (event) {

    if (validate()) {
        var viewModel = {
            "AssessmentId": $('#assessmentId').val(),
            "AdmissionDetailsAndReviewsId": $('#adminDetailsAndReviewsId').val(),
            "AssessmentTypeId": $('#AssessmentSelectionId').val(),
            "DateMostRecent": $('#dateMostRecent').val(),
            "IQSpecifyOrOther": $("#iqSpecifyOrOther").val(),
            "Score": $('#score').val(),
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("SaveGeneralAssessment", "Assessments")",
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": "@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()" },
            datatype: "json",
            data: viewModel,
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#mdAddAssessment').modal('hide')
                reloadAssessment();
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            }
        });
    };
});

function reloadAssessment() {
    var assessmentTablesDiv = $('#assessmentTablesDiv');
    var id = $('#adminDetailsAndOverviewId').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("LoadAssessmentTables", "Assessments")",
        data: { id: id },
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            assessmentTablesDiv.replaceWith(data);
        }
    });
}

I don't want to reload the whole page as any other data entered on the page that hasn't been saved will be lost.
Any ideas?
Thanks

.html() instead of .replaceWith(): this preserves the #assessmentTablesDiv element without a chance of event-binding complications.
success: function (data) {
    assessmentTablesDiv.html(data);
},

Handling Success and Failure Asynchronously Using .done() and .fail()
.done(function (response) {
    $('#mdAddAssessment').modal('hide');
    reloadAssessment();
})
.fail(function (response) {
    alert("An error occurred: " + JSON.stringify(response));
});

It should reload smooth, without reloading the page.
